# Is there a built in Zend framework popup window?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, popup

**Is there a built in Zend framework popup window?**

I want to know if there is a feature built in the zend framework that when you click a link it opens up an action in a nice pop up window such as smoothbox, lightbox etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, it should have.

But, the answer is No, it does not have it.

**Why it should have?**

Zend Framework is a complete set of tools for creating website's back-end and front-end both. The parsing on zend server is effective when the programmer creates an entire website using Zend* functions. On Apache server it is just a web application which runs the entire code as an application and compiles all of the libraries. On Zend server, it already has the compiled stack of libraries and all it requires to compile is your code (application/) and that's all, it is all set. Which is why part of front-ends are taken care of by Zend_Form* functions and people who argue that ZF has nothing to do with front-end , well then that framework would be incomplete! We do not just have views/scripts or views/helpers we even have layouts and many functions to support front-end.

**Why it doesn't have?**

Zend has created the framework to accomplish many things however, not everything is possible, even today we have jQuery haters! So compiling the list of things which a developer *might* use is bit of a problem. However, they have left the option for developers by giving them ability to edit HTML directly into the views and have also given decorators as a class under Zend_Form*.

**What you should do?**
Get a custom code of add a class and use Javascript for pop up. (personally, I prefer lightbox) rather than annoying users by giving a window pop up!

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually *Zend Framework* does have some components available to you that may be of use.

If you have downloaded the *"Full Package"* version of ZF it includes the *Dojo Toolkit* which is supported by the core `Zend_Dojo` component. While `Zend_Dojo` appears to be primarily designed for working with form elements, there does appear to be some support for more advanced options.
The Dojo Toolkit can be located at the path `\ZendFramework\externals\dojo`.

Also with the the *"Full Package"* is the *ZendX* library, located at `\ZendFramework\extras\library\ZendX` which includes a component to help integrate Jquery with ZF applications.

I do not as yet use javascript much so I have no idea how complete and useful these components are, I just know they exist.

Answer (score 0):

No, popups are handled by Javascript and you just named couple of packages like 'lightbox' to use for get this effect.

Comment: there is no need to for features you can easily be handled with other tools and one or two additional lines of markup. Zend is bloated enough already

Answer (score 0):

There isn't even a built-in `href` generator. I mean the `<a>` tag. Instead you have the url helper which generates the url in order to be echoed inside the `<a href="...">`

**Zend Framework runs on the server side**, the view template itself is rendered on the client side. There's no popups on the server side, but you can achieve that with a view helper in order to generate the  tag with the necessary attributes used by a JS component (i.e. ligthbox)

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html